Laravel translation fallback is not working
Laravle version: '8.83.27'
In case if localization file is not have a key for translation __() is not used a fallback it return a key instead of fallback string
In config/app.php I have:
'fallback_locale' => 'en' 
I have empty json at:
resources/lang/es.json
Use a code:
\App::setLocale('en');
$en = __('tg.lang.answer'); 
//get 'some answer text'
\App::setLocale('es');
$es = __('tg.lang.answer'); 
//get 'tg.lang.answer'

Expected that $i should return the fallback string from 'en' locale.
I debuged vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.php
found that is processed fallback 'en' but search key in some $group = 'tg' where it not presend

Can you show the structure and files in the resources\lang folder. You say you have an empty file es.json but where are the English strings stored?

    resources/lang         resources/lang/en        resources/lang/en/auth.php        resources/lang/en/pagination.php        resources/lang/en/passwords.php        resources/lang/en/validation.php        resources/lang/en.json        resources/lang/es.json

English strings stored  in en.json

Generally, if you are using short keys for get string to display the translations are stored in php files under a folder for each language. The example from the documentation is:
/resources
    /lang
        /en
            messages.php
        /es
            messages.php

If you use json files it's expected that the full string is used as the key expects the full string you want to display as the key. The example for this in the docs is
{
    "I love programming.": "Me encanta programar."
}

You appear to be using short keys but storing the strings in json files. While this should work it might confuse other Laravel developers when reading the code.
Your short keys are also confusing, why have you put multiple periods in the key?
You have tg.lang.answer when the standard format is [file].[key], the example in the docs shows
echo __('messages.welcome');

which will look for the key welcome in the messages.php file under the appropriate language folder. The alternative using json files is to put the full message as the argument to the translate function
echo __('I love programming.');

I appreciate this does not directly answer your question but I wanted to include more information that I could put in a comment. If you can add a comment regarding the key format you have chosen, and what happens if you change the file type to store the strings, that might give some more information.
